# What are the differences between the branches under the linux-next repository?

Tags: linux-kernel

The linux-next repository has master,apkm,apkm-base,pending-fixes and stable branch.What are the differences ? I'm following the master branch now,but the commit record has changed when I follow next time. which branch should I follow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TL;DR: you should follow tags in the repository, which are in the format *next-YYYYmmdd*.

Linux Next repository is almost on a daily basis rebuilt from scratch. Basically the main branch is *master* against content of which the tags are given.

- **pending-fixes**: the fixes which are going to the next vanilla release candidate or final release
- **akpm**, **akpm-base**: those are from Andrew Morton’s quilt series, that’s why it needs special handling (he is not using Git)